# How can I fix "ld: cannot find -lv4l2" when compiling the rscam crate?

Tags: rust, webcam

I'm trying to write a movement detection camera using the rscam crate:

```rs
use rscam;
fn main() {}
```

This is my Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "MovementDetectionCamera"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["whitespace"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
rscam = "0.5"
```

I'm getting this error after running `cargo build`:

```
   Compiling MovementDetectionCamera v0.1.0 (/home/whitespace/Development/Rust/MovementDetectionCamera)
warning: unused import: `rscam`
 --> src/main.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use rscam;
  |     ^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_imports)]` on by default

warning: crate `MovementDetectionCamera` should have a snake case name
  |
  = note: `#[warn(non_snake_case)]` on by default
  = help: convert the identifier to snake case: `movement_detection_camera`

error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "cc" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-Wl,-z,noexecstack" "-m64" "-Wl,--eh-frame-hdr" "-L" "/home/whitespace/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "/home/whitespace/Development/Rust/MovementDetectionCamera/target/debug/deps/MovementDetectionCamera-c4f14d4f0500a6ed.MovementDetectionCamera.8tj1wlf8-cgu.0.rcgu.o" "/home/whitespace/Development/Rust/MovementDetectionCamera/target/debug/deps/MovementDetectionCamera-c4f14d4f0500a6ed.MovementDetectionCamera.8tj1wlf8-cgu.1.rcgu.o" "/home/whitespace/Development/Rust/MovementDetectionCamera/target/debug/deps/MovementDetectionCamera-c4f14d4f0500a6ed.MovementDetectionCamera.8tj1wlf8-cgu.2.rcgu.o" "/home/whitespace/Development/Rust/MovementDetectionCamera/target/debug/deps/MovementDetectionCamera-c4f14d4f0500a6ed.MovementDetectionCamera.8tj1wlf8-cgu.3.rcgu.o" "/home/whitespace/Development/Rust/MovementDetectionCamera/target/debug/deps/MovementDetectionCamera-c4f14d4f0500a6ed.MovementDetectionCamera.8tj1wlf8-cgu.4.rcgu.o" "/home/whitespace/Development/Rust/MovementDetectionCamera/target/debug/deps/MovementDetectionCamera-c4f14d4f0500a6ed.MovementDetectionCamera.8tj1wlf8-cgu.5.rcgu.o" "/home/whitespace/Development/Rust/MovementDetectionCamera/target/debug/deps/MovementDetectionCamera-c4f14d4f0500a6ed.MovementDetectionCamera.8tj1wlf8-cgu.6.rcgu.o" "-o" "/home/whitespace/Development/Rust/MovementDetectionCamera/target/debug/deps/MovementDetectionCamera-c4f14d4f0500a6ed" "/home/whitespace/Development/Rust/MovementDetectionCamera/target/debug/deps/MovementDetectionCamera-c4f14d4f0500a6ed.ajcx5rph7u75klg.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-zrelro" "-Wl,-znow" "-nodefaultlibs" "-L" "/home/whitespace/Development/Rust/MovementDetectionCamera/target/debug/deps" "-L" "/home/whitespace/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/home/whitespace/Development/Rust/MovementDetectionCamera/target/debug/deps/librscam-41aa5245806004dd.rlib" "/home/whitespace/Development/Rust/MovementDetectionCamera/target/debug/deps/liblibc-6c90405dba7f3e8e.rlib" "-Wl,--start-group" "/home/whitespace/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-0a9489cf400f65e4.rlib" "/home/whitespace/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libpanic_unwind-ff5dc44c66f8c479.rlib" "/home/whitespace/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libminiz_oxide-3317c66a83501f9c.rlib" "/home/whitespace/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libadler-5d8dec11fc25537d.rlib" "/home/whitespace/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libobject-3af2a9328550e2a6.rlib" "/home/whitespace/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libaddr2line-3092e2ecef0f49f1.rlib" "/home/whitespace/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libgimli-29b776c021389465.rlib" "/home/whitespace/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_demangle-e8873bd287db0d28.rlib" "/home/whitespace/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libhashbrown-1171b49d77e47426.rlib" "/home/whitespace/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-c29894d22dc88b51.rlib" "/home/whitespace/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libunwind-796a7750df3d8218.rlib" "/home/whitespace/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcfg_if-ff7772d803d3e0de.rlib" "/home/whitespace/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liblibc-dae3eac9cfa44200.rlib" "/home/whitespace/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liballoc-0fa02f580e987af5.rlib" "/home/whitespace/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-7f7254233be843ed.rlib" "/home/whitespace/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcore-1395c6db3d116086.rlib" "-Wl,--end-group" "/home/whitespace/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcompiler_builtins-b4bd87926720b651.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lv4l2" "-lgcc_s" "-lutil" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lm" "-ldl" "-lc"
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lv4l2
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: The compiler can't find the video4linux2 libraries (libv4l), which can usually be found in your distribution's package repository.

Answer (score 1):

Installing the libv4l-dev library fixed it for me. If youre on Ubuntu you can use this command.

```
sudo apt-get install -y libv4l-dev
```